# Is there an accepted/received way of checking to see if a person (phone number) is in the Contact List?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is there an accepted/received way of checking to see if a person (phone number) is in the Contact List?

I'm hoping there's something I can call like this:

bool bInContactList = InContactList("1415922353");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not as simple as you want but you can query a Contacts content provider for the contact associated with a phone number:

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[] {PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
if (c.getCount() > 0) {
    // there is some contact
} else {
    // there is no contacts with phoneNumber
}
```

The application needs `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` permission to access contacts data.

You can check [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for further references about content providers and [android.providers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html) package documentation for the list of available standard providers in Android.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you did not provide enough information about the language you are talking about. If you use Java -for example- you have a contains method (common to all collections) so, if you want to know if a certain String is contained in a collection you could do it by invoking this method:

boolean found = someCollection.conmtains("1415922353");

Comment: I would think Java would be assumed, as this is an Android question.